# Saving a specific simulation time

Tags: matlab, storage, simulink

I have a two-track model implemented in simulink. To control the velocity I use a PID-controller, so that the the output of the velocity looks like this:

[image: simulink]

now I want to implement a MATLAB function or simulink block that tracks the time when the velocity reaches a steady-state-behaviour and puts it into some kind of storage. I tried to implement something like this via the following MATLAB function with MATLAB-function-block:

```
function y = fcn(t,v,dv,tv)
  %#codegen
  if (v==tv+0.01) & (dv<0)
  y=t
end
```

t is the clock-signal, v the velocity, dv the first derivation of the velocity and tv is the targetvelocity. The problem about this function is that there "y is not defined on some execution paths". do you have any ideas how to make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: simulink]

I solved the problem without a MATLAB function using the simulink blocks `data store memory` and its `read` & `write` blocks. The signal that is coming in from bottom right side is the momentary velocity. The `if` statement is

```
(u1 >= 22.2) & (u1<=22.3) & (u2<0)
```

Since simulink is using time steps and the momentary velocity will never be exactly `22.2`, you can not use `u1==22.2`

Answer (score 3):

```
function y = fcn(t,v,dv,tv)
  %#codegen
y = zeros(length(t),1); % Initialise the array
for ii = 1:length(t)
  if (v==tv+0.01) & (dv<0)
  y(ii)=t;
  else
  y(ii)=0;
  end
end
y(y==0)=[];
end
```

Two changes: added a semicolon after `y=t` to force it to not print it every time it is set. Second, your question, `else y=[];`, which means that `y` will be an empty matrix if you do not adhere to your `if` statement.

It now stores a `0` each time you do not adhere to the `if` statement. The line `y(y==0)=[];` deletes all zeros, comment this line if you want your `y` to be the same length as the input variables.

```
function y = fcn(t,v,dv,tv)
  %#codegen
y = zeros(length(t),1); % Initialise the array
ii=1;
while exist(t)
  if (v==tv+0.01) & (dv<0)
  y(ii)=t;
  else
  y(ii)=0;
  end
ii = ii+1;
end
y(y==0)=[];
end
```

Comment: allright, this is the first part of my problem, but still doesn't solve it. probably i didn't make that clear enough: i want the function to memorize the time when the if-statement was true for the FIRST time. But if i leave it like this, it will overwrite y on every simulationstep, because the if will always be true after that first time. can you solve this as well?

Comment: well, this looks good to me, but unfortunatly doesn't work with simulink. i think it's because simulink cannot determine the length of t or t always has a length of 1 for each simulation step.... the error says this:

 Dimension 2 is fixed on the left-hand side but varies on the right ([1 x 1] ~= [1 x :?]).

Function 'Steuerung/MATLAB Function' (#194.168.169), line 10, column 1:
"y"
Launch diagnostic report.
Component: MATLAB Function | Category: Coder error

Comment: Ah, that does pose a problem. Let me see if I can implement a `while` loop code. Done, though Im not sure whether this actually works. It's an interesting problem.

Comment: the exist-function doesn't work with simulink unfortunatly, i already tried something with that.

Comment: ok, i now found a solution to the problem without a matlab function in simulink itself. if you are interested in the solution, tell me, and i will add an answer. thanks for your efforts and interest anyway!

Comment: Add the answer, it's good to fill the knowledge base SO strives to be. As well, you can accept your own answer and get reputation that way ;)

Comment: well since i cannot post images with my reputation and imgur doesn't safe them very long, i don't know, if this will fill the knowledge base, but i posted it anyway

Answer (score 3):

In SimuLink add a second output and a fifth input to your function.  Then use that new output as a feedback to the function.

```
function [y, output] = fcn(t,v,dv,tv,input)
y = 0;
output = input;
if (v == tv + 0.01) && (dv < 0)
    y = t;
    if (input == -1)
        output = t;
    end
end
```

Attach the `output` to an `IC` block where you set the `input` initial value to `-1` or whatever value you want to use.  Then attach the `IC` block to the `input` of the function.  `output` will be feedback constantly through the function.  Once it's set it will reatin it's value forever.

Comment: thanks for your efforts, but i solved the problem on my own meanwhile. since your solution works, i upvoted it anyway!